# mongodb: query for the time period between two date fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have documents in the following schema saved in my mongoDB:

```
{
  createdDate: Date,
  lastUpdate: Date
}
```

is it possible to query for documents where the period of time between creation and the last update is e.g. greater than one day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$dateDiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/) aggregation operator:

```
// { created: ISODate("2021-12-05T13:20"), lastUpdate: ISODate("2021-12-06T05:00") }
// { created: ISODate("2021-12-04T09:20"), lastUpdate: ISODate("2021-12-05T18:00") }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    $expr: {
      $gt: [
        { $dateDiff: { startDate: "$created", endDate: "$lastUpdate", unit: "hour" } },
        24
      ]
    }
  }}
])
// { created: ISODate("2021-12-04T09:20"), lastUpdate: ISODate("2021-12-05T18:00") }
```

This computes the number of hours of difference between the `created` and `lastUpdate` dates and checks if it's more than `24` `hour`s.

Answer (score 11):

Best option is to use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) aggregation pipeline stage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$gt": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$lastUpdate", "$createdDate" ] },
                    1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

So you are looking at the milliseconds value from the difference being greater than the milliseconds value for one day. The [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) does the math for the difference, and when two dates are subtracted the difference in miliseconds is returned.

The `$redact` operator takes a logical expression as "if", and where that condition is `true` it takes the action in "then" which is to `$$KEEP` the document. Where it is `false` then the document is removed from results with `$$PRUNE`.

Note that since this is a logical condition and not a set value or a range of values, then an "index" is not used.

Since the operations in the aggregation pipeline are natively coded, this is the fastest execution of such a statement that you can get though.

The alternate is JavaScript evaluation with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). This takes a JavaScript function expression that needs to similarly return a `true` or `false` value. In the shell you can shorthand like this:

```js
db.collection.find(function() {
    return ( this.lastUpdate.valueOf() - this.createdDate.valueOf() )
       > ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 );
})
```

Same thing, except that JavaScript evalution requires interpretation and will run much slower than the `.aggregate()` equivalent. By the same token, this type of expression cannot use an index to optimize performance.

For the **best** results, store the difference in the document. Then you can simply query directly on that property, and of course you can index it as well.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! As someone coming from SQL I did not expect it to be that verbose...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) ( 3.6 mongo version operator ) to use aggregation functions in regular query.

Compare [`query operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) vs [`aggregation comparison operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

```
db.col.find({$expr:{$gt:[{"$subtract":["$lastUpdate","$createdDate"]},1000*60*60*24]}})
```

Comment: will that have better performance than a standard aggregate query or is it the same?