# Python FastApi Motor Mongodb: Aggregate Data by field calculations

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation, fastapi, motorola

I'm running a fast-api app with mongodb connected by motor.
I implented an async crud repo which works just fine.
Now I'm looking for a possibility to filter for documents by subtracting two fields with eachother.

Story:

I'm running a cron job which executes every 1 Minute. In my documents I have a field `last_run` and `interval`. last_run is a timestamp and interval is a number ( seconds ) and can be different for each document.

Now I only need the data, when the last_run + interval timetamp is smaller than the current time ( when the cron job runs). I've searched the docs but could not find an example for such a scenario.

Comment: There is no need to perform the calculation in Mongo - wouldn't querying for any document where the field is smaller than `current time - interval` work just as good, and allow for indexes to be used?

Comment: yes but interval could be different for each document as it can be set and changed indivitually.

Comment: Ah, good point. The usual straight forward strategy in those cases is to have a `next_run` field to use as a lookup field to find out when the next run should take place. Not being very familiar with Mongo I'd possibly look at having a calculated field: https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/saas/calculated-fields/ - otherwise look at something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176905/mongodb-query-for-the-time-period-between-two-date-fields - not sure if a calculated field would be able to use an index (the last one wouldn't).

Comment: The next_run field is a good idea. This could be updated on each run as well as when the user updates the interval value. As the process is not time critical even if one interval is skipped, this should do the trick. Thank you.